# Attempt to present QLPreviewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy issue

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to open a downloaded file in Xamarin Forms for IOS platform using UIDocumentInteractionController and access platform specific class through webservice but it is giving me the issue as 'Attempt to present QLPreviewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy'

```
public void viewFile(string path)
        {
            var PreviewController = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl
                                                (NSUrl.FromFilename(path));
            PreviewController.Delegate = new UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass
                                       (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentedViewController);
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                PreviewController.PresentPreview(true);
            });
        }
```

Following is the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass code:

```
public class UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate   {
            UIViewController ownerVC;
            public UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass(UIViewController vc)
            {
                ownerVC = vc;
            }
            public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
           {
                return ownerVC;
            }
            public override UIView ViewForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
            {
              return ownerVC.View;
            }
        }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var fileinfo = new FileInfo(path);
var previewController = new QLPreviewController();
previewController.DataSource = new PreviewControllerDataSource(fileinfo.FullName, fileinfo.Name);
UINavigationController controller = FindNavigationController();
            
if (controller != null)
{                     
             controller.PresentViewController((UIViewController)previewController, true, (Action)null);
}
```